# ColdFusion application seems to favor one node of cluster

Tags: coldfusion, cluster-computing, coldfusion-9

We have a number of Coldfusion applications (CF 9, multiserver on Linux) which run on a pair of servers front-ended by a pair of Apache web servers. It seems that 90% of the traffic is going to the first CF node. We've used dynatrace to track this and both the number of sessions and the time spent on both nodes are etremly skewed. It does seem too that a large percentage of the time spent on node 1 is spent in database copmmunications (Oracle) but node 2 shows hardly any database activity.

Are there any general reccommedations on coding applications for a coldfusion cluster or any other ways to diagnose the problem?

**Edit 1**

The flow as I understand it is:

F5 load balancer -> web server (where siteminder validates authorization) -> CF

**Edit 2**

From the CF side, the cluster is set up with round robin scheduling and both sticky sessions and replicate sessions enabled.

Comment: You don't mention what it is you're using to balance the traffic? That'll be the component that will be relevant to this, not the ColdFusion servers or Apache.

Comment: Not only _what_ you are using to balance the traffic but also _how_ you are balancing the traffic. Are you using "sticky" sessions? Etc.

Comment: you have to put more details

Comment: What other detail is needed now?

Answer (score 1):

Keith, as Adam said the f5 is the key here. How is it configured. There are a lot of possibilities but here are a few that come to mind.

- The F5 is configured to balance based on CPU usage and the "10%" server has high usage for some reason or another (maybe a non CF reason), so traffic is shunted off to the other server.
- The high traffic is coming from something that looks like a single session to the F5 and because it is set up to be "sticky" it is going to the same server over and over. For example, maybe it sees bot traffic (which comes in undecorated by cookies and params) as all one session because it matches (i.e. it has no cookies or url params).
- Along with the last point perhaps it is a single session after all accounting for ALL the traffic. We recently had such a case where a single IP from the  department of transportation (go figure) was hammering a server and utilizing 50% of it's resources. A DOS attack (note, not a DDOS) could possibly look like a single session and thus (because of sticky sessions) arrive at the same server.

You can see that this list could go on :)

On a separate note you are clustering your sessions for failover. That means sessions from server A must be copied to server B and vice versa - a task that is occuring constantly between these nodes and servers. There are a lot of nuances to that configuration and I generally counsel folks against it if it is not needed. Stable servers in a cluster with a hardware load balancer provide quite effective redundancy - but it's true when one server goes down folks lose their session (assuming regular CF sessions in memory). The goal is to get to the point where that is a very rare exception.

Consider what happens when you add a 3rd server to your cluster. They must now all replicate - increasing your memory and bandwidth requirements exponentially.

So... if you must do this make sure you are doing one important thing. Code your application so that sessions are NOT created by agents and bots. In other words make sure that "every session is a planned and wanted session" (with my apologies to Joycelyn Elders).

Hope this helps. Good luck!